# How to fix Zoom borking computer audio?

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, zoom.app

I've noticed when in Zoom meetings, all audio playing on my computer, even to audio outputs which Zoom isn't using, gets distorted and becomes monophonic. I often want to listen to high quality music while on a Zoom, and having everything sounds essentially like a phone call does not help anything.

Any idea what could be causing this, and if it's possible to get around? I was thinking Zoom might be enabling some sort of communications mode but I couldn't find any information on that.

Obviously, enabling original sound and changing settings within the Zoom application hasn't done anything.

Comment: This s standard Bluetooth and has been asked here before. Basically if you have a microphone input via Bluetooth the higher quality audio can't be sekectec

Comment: Yeah just figured that out, SCO being stupid, probably will close. Do you know any way to force fix it instead of just changing the input?

Comment: The 'fix' is a wired headset. BT can't do both structures at once.